# (polynomial question) what is the value of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$?

Tags: polynomials

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are roots of the equation $x^3-rx + 20 = 0$, where $r$ is a real number, we can say that the value of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, plug the values into the polynomial and add them together,
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=r(a+b+c)-60$$
But by the Vieta formula for the polynomial, $a+b+c=0$, thus
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=-60$$
The Vieta formulas come from the equation
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc=x^3-rx+20$$
Thus, the Vieta formulas are
$$a+b+c=0$$
$$ab+bc+ca=-r$$
$$abc=-20$$

Answer (score 2):

As we have for $a,b,c$ that
$$x^3=rx-20$$
Then
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=(ra-20)+(rb-20)+(rc-20)=r(a+b+c)-60$$
Then using Vieta's formulas we get
$$a+b+c=0$$
Hence
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=-60$$